# Is it OK to call __init__ from __setstate__

Tags: python, pickle, init, getstate

I'm enhancing an existing class that does some calculations in the `__init__` function to determine the instance state. Is it ok to call `__init__()` from `__getstate__()` in order to reuse those calculations?

Comment: If the class is yours, sure! I would recommend separating these calculations into a classmethod and calling that from both `__init__` and `__getstate_`

Comment: I would second @Kroltan - I would move those calculations out into a separate instance/class method rather than call `__init__` again.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to call `__init__` from `__setstate__` or `__getstate__`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize reactions from Kroltan and jonsrharpe:

## Technically it is OK

Technically it will work and if you do it properly, it can be considered OK.

## Practically it is tricky, avoid that

If you edit the code in future and touch `__init__`, then it is easy (even for you) to forget about use in `__setstate__` and then you enter into difficult to debug situation (asking yourself, where it comes from).

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        # some calculation stuff here
    def __setstate__(self, state)
        self.__init__()
```

The calculation stuff is better to get isolated into another shared method:

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        self._shared_calculation()   

    def __setstate__(self, state)
        self._shared_calculation()

    def _shared_calculation(self):
        #some calculation stuff here
```

This way you shall notice.

Note: use of "_" as prefix for the shared method is arbitrary, you do not have to do that.

Comment: I find it weirder that objects are constructed without calling __init__.

Comment: @cz Remember: **__new__()** constructs objects. **__init__()** just initializes instance variables. You can even define a class `class A: pass` and create instances from it `a = A()` because of this.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually preferable to write a method called [`__getnewargs__`](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) instead.  That way, the Pickling mechanism will call `__init__` for you automatically.

Comment: did not manage to make it work. read the doc and still. resorted to methods above

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to Customize the constructor class `__init__` in a subclass. Ideally it is better to have to one Constructor class & change according to your need in Subclass

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, job=None, pay=0):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.pay = pay

class Manager(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, pay):                   
        Person.__init__(self, name, 'title', pay)  # Run constructor with 'title'
```

Calling constructors class this way turns out to be a very common coding pattern in Python. By itself, Python uses inheritance to look for and call only one `__init__` method at construction time—the lowest one in the class tree.

If you need higher `__init__` methods to be run at construction time, you must call them manually, and usually through the superclass name as in shown in the code above. his way you augment the Superclass constructor & replace the logic in subclass altogether to your liking

As suggested by Jan it is tricky & you will enter difficult debug situation if you call it in same class

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question which was about `__setstate__` calling `__init__`.